# Dropdown not selected properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hi all i am using `angulajs` and bind `drop down` my functionality i have one `drop down` when i select the `drop down` values i have to store into `drop down`  selected values in cookies after page reloading i have same values as selected index what i selected that is my functionality it's working fine and correctly. but after page reloading i am not able to select `drop down` value in first time when i select first time it's automatically go to select option i don't know why help how to solve

## controller

```
 var FacilityIDs=[{FacilityID:1,Name:'one'},{FacilityID:2,Name:'two'}]
        $scope.FacilityChange = function (data) {
            debugger;

            $cookieStore.put("FacilityID1", data);

        };
```

## Html

```
<select id="Facility" form="form" 
    ng-change="FacilityChange(value.storedObject)"
     ng-model="value.storedObject">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="FacilityId in FacilityIDs" 
     ng-selected="FacilityId.FacilityID ==FacilityID1"
    value="{{FacilityId.FacilityID}}" 
     >

     {{FacilityId.name}}
       </option>

    </select>
```

Comment: What is `value` object in the function that you are calling in html?

Comment: just modal name

Comment: Are you able to see `value.storedObject` value?

Comment: i am send the data from one controller to another controller using factory so only i used
app.factory('StoreService', function () {
    return {
        storedObject: ''
    };


});

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your controller code.

```
 var FacilityIDs=[{FacilityID:1,Name:'one'},{FacilityID:2,Name:'two'}]

 $scope.FacilityID1 = $cookieStore.get('FacilityID1') || '';

 $scope.FacilityChange = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $scope.FacilityID1 = data;
    $cookieStore.put("FacilityID1", data);

 };
```

You need to retrieve the data and store it in `$scope.FacilityID1` as you are uswing it in `ng-selected`.

All the best.

Comment: When to get `$scope.FacilityID1`?

Comment: Yeah. That's why answered.

Comment: What problem you are facing now? Can't you get the data from `$cookieStore`?

Comment: i am get data from cookiestore i am not able to select dropdown

Comment: Did you update the code as I answered. Then where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`$cookieStore` service is deprecated. Better go for [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)